# How to save a document in MongoDB by r2d2 and actix?

Tags: mongodb, rust, actix-web, r2d2

I am new to Rust and was trying to create a webserver with Actix-web to perform CRUD operations via MongoDB. The first API I am creating is to save a simple document in MongoDB by something received from a POST request. The code for the post request handler function is:

```
extern crate r2d2;
extern crate r2d2_mongodb;

use r2d2::Pool;
use r2d2_mongodb::mongodb::db::ThreadedDatabase;
use r2d2_mongodb::{ConnectionOptions, MongodbConnectionManager};

use actix_web::{web, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Responder};
use bson::{doc, Bson, Document};

async fn post_request(info: web::Json<Info>, pool: web::Data<Pool<MongodbConnectionManager>>) -> HttpResponse {
    let name: &str = &info.name;
    let connection = pool.get().unwrap();
    let doc = doc! {
      "name": name
    };
    let result = connection.collection("user").insert_one(doc, None);
    HttpResponse::Ok().body(format!("username: {}", info.name))
}
```

I am using r2d2 to establish a connection pool for MongoDB instead of opening and closing a connection. The error i am getting is

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:59
   |
17 |     let result = connection.collection("user").insert_one(doc, None);
   |                                                           ^^^ expected struct `OrderedDocument`, found struct `bson::Document`
```

The `insert_one` function doc says it accepts a `bson::Document` but when I give that to it, it says `` expected struct `r2d2_mongodb::mongodb::ordered::OrderedDocument` ``

Here are my Cargo.toml dependancies

```
mongodb = "1.1.1"
actix-web = "3.3.2"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
r2d2-mongodb = "0.2.2"
r2d2 = "0.8.9"
serde = "1.0.118"
bson = "1.1.0"
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: @kmdreko sure let me edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `r2d2-mongodb` is outdated and no longer supported, the `r2d2` crate [marks it as](https://crates.io/crates/r2d2):

> deprecated: official driver handles pooling internally

So I recommend you don't use it. You should be able to use a [`mongodb::Client`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/1.1.1/mongodb/struct.Client.html) or [`mongodb::Database`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/1.1.1/mongodb/struct.Database.html) instead of a `Pool<MongodbConnectionManager>`.

---

The reason for the error is the `r2d2-mongodb` uses an older version of `mongodb` (0.3) and therefore an older version of `bson` (0.13) that is incompatible with the version of `bson` you're using (1.1.0). You'll probably have similar compatibility issues with the `mongodb` crate itself as well. You can fix it by lowering your dependencies:

```
mongodb = "0.3.0"
bson = "0.13.0"
```

Though, as I brought up before, I don't recommend it.

Comment: Yes i am considering the same. Can you tell me how to establish a connection pool on mongodb rust driver?

Comment: @Alonzo All you need to do is create a `Client`, it does pooling automatically. You can follow the documentation on the [mongodb crate](https://docs.rs/mongodb/1.1.1/mongodb/).